# Format VSTS Repo Step with field with rest API

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

Is it possible to format VSTS "Repo Steps" section with html formatting like Bold and including Paragraphs using VSTS Rest API?

Comment: Do you mean the value of Repo Steps?

Comment: Yes, I need to problematically add formatted text to Repo Steps section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update Repo Step value by using Update a field REST API, for example, : bold, : paragraph.

Simple request:

```
https://XXX.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/workitems/110?api-version=1.0
```

Data:

```
[
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps",
    "value": "<div>He<b>llo</b></div><div>wo<i>r<b>d</b>and</i></div><div>te<u><b><i>st</i></b></u></div>"
  }
]
```

The result:
He**llo**

wor**d**and

te*st*